# Accessing ng-repeat index value from custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

**Hello,**

I have made a custom html directive using AngularJS to plot data that I get from a HTTP request.

I've run into an issue where I can't access the $index property of ng-repeat to select the relevant data sets in the returned data to plot.

**My code looks like this:**

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <form class="sidebar" ng-submit="getData()">
         //some selection method
         <button type="submit">Select</button>

        </form>
    </div>
<chart ng-if="data" ng-repeat="item in data" id="{{ $index }}" val="data"></kpi-chart>
```

getData() returns an object array called *"data"* containing the measurements I'm interested in plotting in a nested object.

```
app.directive('chart',  function () {
//setup of initial object
    return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    terminal: true,
    scope: {
        val: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        // Setup of SVG object on page

        var orig = newVal[$index];
```

I want this orig, here at the end, to refer to the **$index** from ng-repeat above to make it plot graphs with the correct data, with a 1 graph to 1 data set ratio.

How can I make the ng-repeat $index value avaliable to the directive so that it knows which data set to access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `attrs.$observe` to get the value of `{{$index}}` which will put watch on interpolation value.

**Code**

```
attrs.$observe('id', function(newVal, oldVal){
    if(newVal) {
       console.log("Index of ng-repeat ", newVal)
    }
})
```

Another alternative way would be you could have another variable inside isolated scope that can have index value.

**Markup**

```
<chart ng-if="data" ng-repeat="item in data" 
  id="{{$index}}" index="{{$index}}" val="data">
</chart>
```

**Code**

```
scope: {
    val: '=',
    index: '@'
},
```

Then you could have `scope.index` inside you link function would give an access to the index of `ng-repeat`.

Comment: @Alex did you followed second way..that would be nicer

Comment: Yes, I did! I saw your edit and used that instead, worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @Alex Glad to here that it does helped you..Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use attrs:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    var ind = attrs['id'];
    var orig = newVal[ind];
```